Descent for étale covers of proper regular models of elliptic curves
Let $K$ be a complete (but think Henselian suffice for purposes of this question) local field of characteristic $0$ with residue field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ and ring of integers $R=\mathcal{O}_{K}$.
Let $E=(E/K,o_E)$ be an elliptic curve and $\mathcal{C}$ be a minimal proper regular model of $E$ over $R$ of split multiplicative type, i.e. the special fibre $\mathcal{C}_{k}$ has configuration of Kodaira type $I_n$ which means intuitively that the special fibre is a loop of circularly configured $\Bbb P_k^1$'s.
The goal is to see that there exist a unique isogeny of elliptic curves $f:(F, o_F) \rightarrow (E, o_E)$ of degree $d$ over $K$ such that  $\mathcal{D}$ - the normalization of $\mathcal{C}$ in $K(F)$ induced by $f$ - is a nodal curve over $R$ with reduced components and to understand its structure.
I have some questions about some steps in the argument Will Sawin gave in his answer here.
Firstly, we observe that finite étale covers $p: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ over $R$ correspond since $R$ is Henselian to finite étale covers $D_k \to C_k$ of the special fibre. Following part confuses me:

An unramified covering is constant over each $\mathbb P^1$ and thus a geometrically connected unramified covering of $\mathcal C$ must geometrically consist of a loop of $\mathbb P^1$s winding around that loop multiple times. There are multiple ways to descend this covering to $k$, but only one where the identity lifts to a $k$-rational point, as it must in an isogeny.

The approach Will suggesting there - so far I understand correctly - is firstly to base change to algebraic closure  $C_k \otimes_k \overline{k}$ and analyze its covers (="geometric covers")there, and then to analyze data descending these down to $k$.
What I do not understand is the italicized part that there are multiple ways to descend this covering to $k$, but that there is only one descent where the identity (...that's the point in $C_k(k)$ corresponding via identifications $E(K) \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}(R) \rightsquigarrow C_k(k)$ to the distinguished point $o_E \in E(K)$) lifts to some $k$-rational point of $D_k$.
Concretely, let us fix a geometric $d$-covering $p_{\overline{k}}:D_{\overline{k}} \to C_k \otimes_k \overline{k}$ given as described above intuitively "by winding $d$-times around" $C_k \otimes_k \overline{k}$.
The question is, why among all descents to $k$ there exist a unique descent to a cover of $C_k$ with distinguished property having a $k$-point over "identity point" (in above sense)?

If $C_k$ is irreducible, the etale fundamental group of $C_k$ is generated (via the homotopy exact sequence) by the (etale) $\pi_1(C_{\overline{k}})$ and $\Gamma_k := Gal(\overline{k}/k)$, the latter realized as the $\pi_1$ of the point $o_{E_k}$. Thus for a given cover defined over $\overline{k}$, the descents are parametrized by their restrictions to $o_{E_k}$. The descent which admits a rational point is the one whose restriction is a trivial cover of $o_{E_k}$. If $C_k$ has multiple components, you might have to normalize and keep track of some gluing data.

@WillChen: generated in which sense? This HES exists when $C_k$ is geometrically connected variety, why do we need the irreducibility assumption? Doesn't the exactness already by usual group theory nonsense imply that the middle term is is generated by generators of left object & preimages of gen's of the right term of the ses?

@WillChen: More concretely, in which sense you mean that $\pi_1(C_k)$ is generated by $\pi_1(C_{\overline{k}})$ and $\Gamma_k$ (so left & right object of HES) depending on irreducibility on $C_k$? Or do you maybe actually refer to geom connectedness of $C_k$?

@WillChen: Ok, Szamuely requires $C_k$ integeral to have HES, let's do it and assume $C_k$ irred. Could you sketch the idea how to see that precisely those descents of a fixed FET of $C_{\overline{k}}$ admit rational point in the fibre over base point (I assume you picked $o_{E_k}$ as base pt, right?) which restrict to triv cover of $o_{E_k}$?

Yes I was thinking of Szamuely's result, though a more convenient version for you is SGA1 Expose IX, Theorem 6.1, which only requires geometric connectedness (not integrality). From that one finds that there exists at most one descent which is totally split above $o_{E_k}$.

@Will Chen: What do you mean by that a descent restricts to a "totally splitting covering" (over $o_{E_k}$)? That this restriction to $o_{E_k}$ admits a section? (This is of course equivlent to having $k$-point in fibre) Or that it becomes trivial cover? If yes, but why it cannot accidentally happen that say two different descents $f_i:D_k \to C_k, i=1,2$ of a cover over $C_{\overline{k}}$ accidentally restrict to different covers $j_o^f_i: j_o^ D_k \to o_{E_k}$ over $o_{E_k}$ (where $j_o: o_{E_k} \to E$ canonical incl) having

each a k-section? But doesnt restriction to trivial cover of $o_{E_k}$ mean that all points in fibre are $k$-rational (=so $deg(f)$ sections)? That's strange, as that would mean that a cover over $o_{E_k}$ admitting one $k$-rational point, has only rational points, or do I missing sth? Therefore I'm not sure why only one of descents restricts to a cover of $o_{E_k}$ admiting a $k$-rational in fibre. Could you maybe elaborate the argument why exactly that descent admts a $k$-rational point, which restricts via $j_o$ above over $o_{E_k}$ to the trivial cover? (...and not others accidently).

Okay let me try my hand at an answer. Specifically, I'll address the final question, which is whether there exists a unique descent of a geometrically connected finite etale connected cover $D_{\overline{k}}\rightarrow C_{\overline{k}}$ to $k$ such that $D_{k}$ admits a rational point. I claim the answer is positive.
The homotopy exact sequence for $C_k$ gives us an action of $\Gamma_k := \text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ on $\overline{\Pi} := \pi_1(C_{\overline{k}})$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is assumed to be of split multiplicative type, $C_k$ must be obtained by gluing some number of $\mathbb{P}^1$'s in a chain along $k$-rational points.
Claim: The action of $\Gamma_k$ must be trivial.
Proof: We know $\overline{\Pi}\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, so $\Gamma_k$ must act via a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) = \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times$. If the action image is nontrivial, then it is nontrivial in some finite quotient, i.e. it acts nontrivially on $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for some $n$. This implies that there exists a $\mathbb{Z}/n$-cover of $C_{\overline{k}}$ which does not descend, as a Galois cover, to $C_k$. However, this is false -- every finite cover of $C_{\overline{k}}$ can be explicitly constructed (as a chain of $n$ $\mathbb{P}^1$'s glued along $k$-rational points) and is easily seen to be defined, as a cover-with-Galois-action, over $k$ (The Galois action of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is just by cyclic rotations of the components).
Remark: If one uses the pro-etale fundamental group of Bhatt-Scholze, then $\pi_1^{pro-et}(C_{\overline{k}})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ (not the profinite completion!). I have not checked all the details, but presumably we can still get a Galois action here, means $\Gamma_k$ would have to act via $\{\pm1\}$. Thus if the action is nontrivial, the action would have to factor through $\text{Gal}(k'/k)$, where $k'/k$ is a separable quadratic extension. This corresponds to the non-split multiplicative case, where the Neron polygon is glued along $k'$-points.
Letting $\Pi := \pi_1(C_k)$, the homotopy exact sequence thus gives us an isomorphism $\Pi\cong\overline{\Pi}\times\Gamma_k$, with $\Gamma_k$ viewed as a subgroup of $\Pi$ via the point $o$. A finite etale cover of degree $n$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\rho : \overline{\Pi}\times\Gamma_k\longrightarrow S_n$, which is in turn the same data as a pair of homomorphisms $\rho|_{\overline{\Pi}} : \overline{\Pi}\rightarrow S_n$ and $\rho|_{\Gamma_k} : \Gamma_k\rightarrow S_n$ such that their images centralize each other.
The cover is geometrically connected if and only if $\rho|_{\overline{\Pi}}$ has transitive image. Since $\overline{\Pi}\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, $\rho|_{\overline{\Pi}}$ is the left regular representation associated to $\mathbb{Z}/n$, sending a generator to an $n$-cycle $\tau\in S_n$. Since $\langle\tau\rangle$ is self-centralizing in $S_n$, the image of $\rho|_{\Gamma_k}$ must be contained in $\langle\tau\rangle$. Thus the only possibility for $\rho|_{\Gamma_k}$ which admits a fixed point is the trivial homomorphism, which also corresponds to the cover which is totally split above $o$. This shows both existence and uniqueness, and moreover that the unique $D_k$ is totally split above $o$.

Could you clarify following point: In paragraph 2 you wrote that that the action by $\Gamma_k$ on $\pi_1(C_{\overline{k}})$ (...by "pulled back" conjugation, right?) is trivial because $C_k$ is given by a chain of $\Bbb P^1$ glued along $k$-points. Could you clarify why the latter implies to former? Maybe it helps to understand this to analyze what this action by $\Gamma_k$ does on $\pi_1(C_{\overline{k}})$ geometrically on level of covers of $C_{\overline{k}}$. Ie if we have such a $n$-covering $p:D \to C_{\overline{k}}$ described via the corresp to action reps

by $\rho: \pi_1(C_{\overline{k}}) \to S_n$, how the "twists" by elements from $\Gamma_k$ actually effect the geometric covers? And so, why if we have $C_k$ given as glued chain of $\Bbb P^1$'s this action is as you claimed trivial?
Maybe the issue can be resolved in a concrete analysis of the cycles in the way you elaborated in answer to in the other question but then deleted. I'm not sure, as unfortunately I wasn't able to read it carefully.

@user267839 I've edited to add some more detail.

Thanks, will need a bit to ponder about. Could you maybe add the deleted answer to the other linked question, or was there something wrong with it? It looked very insightful, it appeared promising to analyse " by hand" the descents via classes of cycle from cohomology if we deal with "more general" situations.

@user267839 There were indeed some issues with my deleted answer, but I've fixed them now and undeleted. Enjoy...

There is one step I still not understand in 3rd paragraph: "[...] If action image is nontrivial, then is nontrivial in some finite quotient, i.e. it acts nontrivially on some $\mathbb{Z}/n$. This implies that there exists a $\mathbb{Z}/n$-cover of $C_{\overline{k}}$ which does not descend, as a Galois cover". Why the nontriviality of its action on such finite quotient  $\mathbb{Z}/n$- serves as "obstruction" condition to admit a descent? (It touches a bit the question first comment under your answer to the other other question on if one can also encode obstructions to descent)

@user267839 In my answer to your other question I showed that descents as a cover correspond to extensions of the monodromy representation to $S_n$. One can also show that descents as a Galois cover correspond to extensions of the representation such that the image is the Galois group, which here is $\mathbb{Z}/n\subset S_n$. Since the image is abelian, such a descent can only exist if the $\Gamma_k$-action descends to the trivial action on $\mathbb{Z}/n$.

Yes right, but your argument was based so far I understand correctly on the assumption that there exist some fixed descent $\xi_0$ and you use it as a "fixing anchor" to "shift" so to say to obtain other descents, but to perform this argument the existence of certain one is crucial. And I was wondering if one can somehow decide starting from a geometric cover $f$ if it admits any descent purely on level of its monodromy/action data $\rho: \pi_1(C_{\overline{k}}) \to S_n$

Note, as your argumentation above shows in this specific situation as $C_{\overline{k}})$ has rather good controllable structure such that we can construct all geometric covers explicitly and see "by hand" that these admits descents. But my question was aiming if we can for some cover of a geometric space $\overline{X} = X \otimes_k \overline{k}$ we can from expectating the structure of its monodromy data $\rho:\pi_1(\overline{X}) \to S_n$ to answer the question if there exist some descent or note? Maybe in terms of some appropriate obstruction group? Or is it to broad in that generality?
